# Creating a dynamic function in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm creating a module for a deck of cards. I want the Deck object to be able to accept another implementation of the shuffle method I have written below.

I was originally thinking that my shuffle method should accept a parameter that is any object that responds to shuffle. Is that a good approach here?

I'm not sure exactly how to approach this in Ruby.

```
module PlayingCards
  class Deck
    RANKS = [*2..10, 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King', 'Ace']
    SUITS = %w{ Clubs Diamonds Hearts Spades }

    attr_accessor :cards, :discarded
    def initialize(options={})
      @cards = []
      @discarded = []
      options[:number_decks] ||= 1

      options[:number_decks].times do
        (RANKS).product(SUITS).each do |rank, suit|
          @cards << Card.new(rank, suit)
        end
      end
    end

    def shuffle()
      cards.push(*discarded).shuffle!
      discarded = []
      self
    end
  end
end
```

This is the hand class that is responsible for drawing cards from the deck and also folding a hand.

```
module PlayingCards
  class Hand
    attr_accessor :deck, :draw_count, :cards, :discarded

    def initialize(args = {})
      @deck = args[:deck]
      @discarded = args[:deck].discarded
      @draw_count = args[:draw_count]
      @cards = []
    end

    def draw
      draw_count.times do
        cards.push(deck.cards[0])
        deck.cards.shift
      end

      cards
    end

    def fold
      discarded.push(cards).flatten!
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I guess you need to place `cards` as last line in `shuffle`, to return the value.

Comment: Don't mind, I missed the `!`

Comment: I'm a bit confused what you're aiming to achieve with the `discarded` variable. My best guess is that each time you `shuffle`, it's possible that some cards will be discarded; but the deck should always be fully restored to its original state before re-shuffling?

Comment: And also, I find it a bit off that the `shuffle` method should **return** the `discarded` list. I would consider it more normal for such a method to return `self`.

Comment: I updated my question to include another class I have, Hand. A Hand can be folded, which pushes the cards into the discarded array, that exists on the Deck object... When a deck shuffles itself it needs to know about both the cards left in the deck and the cards that have been folded.

Comment: also I agree with your second comment, I updated the return value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want the Deck object to be able to accept another implementation of the shuffle method I have written below.

There are a few ways to implement this. There's no single right answer. Here's a few techniques:

1. Just define multiple methods:

   ```
   def shuffle
     cards.push(*discarded).shuffle!
     discarded = []
     self
   end

   # For example
   def shuffle_before_replacing
     cards.shuffle!
     cards.push(*discarded)
     discarded = []
     self
   end
   ```
2. Define a higher order method, for example:

   ```
   SHUFFLE_MODES = {
     standard: ->(cards, discarded) { cards.push(*discarded).shuffle },
     # ...
   }

   def shuffle(mode: :standard)
     cards = SHUFFLE_MODES.fetch(mode).call(cards, discarded)
     discarded = []
     self
   end
   ```
3. Inject a dependency to perform the shuffling, for example:

   ```
   def shuffle(shuffler: Shuffler::Standard)
     shuffler = shuffler.new(cards, discarded)
     shuffler.shuffle
     cards = shuffler.cards
     shuffler = shuffler.discarded
     self
   end

   # ...

   module Shuffler
     class Base
       attr_reader :cards, :discarded
       def initialize(cards, discarded)
         @cards = cards
         @discarded = discarded
       end
     end
   end

   module Shuffler
     class Standard < Base
       def shuffle
         @cards.push(*discarded).shuffle
         @discarded = []
         self
       end
     end
   end

   module Shuffler
     class BeforeReplacing < Base
       def shuffle
         @cards.shuffle!
         @cards.push(*discarded)
         @discarded = []
         self
       end
     end
   end
   ```

   end

One main benefits of this third approach is that you can define `Shuffler`s *independently to the `Deck` class* - so for example, perhaps you'll eventually have multiple types of `Deck` that can each use the `Shuffler` interface in different ways. (For example, maybe you'll want to shuffle different things, or shuffle multiple times.)

Likewise, you can also *test* the `Shuffler`s independently to the `Deck`. This works both ways; you can also now test the `Deck` independently to the `Shuffler` (by passing a mock object into the `Deck#shuffle` method).

This technique is the most advanced of the three, and is something I'd only usually expect an experienced developer to fully utilise, in more complex scenarios. It's hard to say whether such an abstraction is even with the effort yet in your case, given the limited information I have!

---

All code above is untested, so may not be spot on, but hopefully this gives you some inspiration.

Comment: This was really helpful Tom, I got something working from it. Thank you.

Comment: Oh.. yeah, fixed thanks. If you spot a silly mistake like that, feel free to just edit my post!